# if i use wordpress elementor page builder as the same time why we are not using any other builder

Tags: elementor, divi

if we have a plugin. like elementor and divi support like page layout. is diviand elementor we can use now divi or we can use now elementor.  what is your opinion.  is that possible

same page. layour for divi and elementor

Answer (score 0):

So far what I understand about your question because it is not written clearly that you want to use 2 page builder on a single page to design different sections of the page.

Well, In WordPress it is generally not advisable to use multiple page builders simultaneously on the same page. Page builders like Divi and Elementor are designed to be standalone solutions for creating and designing web pages. Mixing them on a single page can lead to conflicts, layout issues, and compatibility problems.

However, you can choose to use one page builder for one page and the other for a different page within the same website. For example, you might use Divi to design one page and Elementor to design another page. This approach is more straightforward and less likely to cause conflicts.

If you need to create different page layouts within the same page, it's better to choose a single page builder and utilize its features for layout customization. Both Divi and Elementor are robust page builders with extensive design capabilities, and you can achieve a wide range of layouts and designs with either one.

Also almost all page builders on the market use their own drag and drop editor. If you use one, the others won’t be accessible.

Some page builders do their best to load previously existing content. But the results are usually not good unless the content comes from the WordPress editor itself.

So, I hope this clears your confusion as it's not recommended to mix multiple page builders on the same page, but you can use Divi for one page and Elementor for another page within your WordPress website.